# Lightbox image viewer positioning in CCS

Tags: html, positioning, lightbox

I want positioning opened images a little down in my website because the menu is covered the opened pictures 5% in top. 
[My website](http://thaifold-phuket.hu/leiras.html)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-margin col-sm-12">
    <div class="content-gallery">
      <div class="gallery-control left"></div>
      <div class="gallery-control right"></div>

      <div class="gallery-img-wrap">
        <a href="http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen3.jpg" class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen3_s.jpg');" data-lightbox="gallery"></a>
        <a href="http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen2.jpg" class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen2_s.jpg');" data-lightbox="gallery"></a>
        <a href="http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen5.jpg" class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen5_s.jpg');" data-lightbox="gallery"></a>
        <a href="http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen6.jpg" class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen6_s.jpg');" data-lightbox="gallery"></a>
        <a href="http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen7.jpg" class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen7_s.jpg');" data-lightbox="gallery"></a>
        <a href="http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen8.jpg" class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen8_s.jpg');" data-lightbox="gallery"></a>
        <a href="http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen9.jpg" class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen9_s.jpg');" data-lightbox="gallery"></a>
        <a href="http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen10.jpg" class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen10_s.jpg');" data-lightbox="gallery"></a>
        <a href="http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen11.jpg" class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('http://phuket.hu/static/img/content/hc4/szalloda_phuketen11_s.jpg');" data-lightbox="gallery"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Preload images */
body:after {
  content: url(../images/lightbox/close.png) url(../images/lightbox/loading.gif)
    url(../images/lightbox/prev.png) url(../images/lightbox/next.png);
  display: none;
}

.lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-family: "KeepCalm", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.lightbox a img {
  border: none;
}

.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-outerContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-container {
  padding: 4px;
}

.lb-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 0;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.lb-cancel {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../images/lightbox/loading.gif) no-repeat;
}

.lb-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lb-container > .nav {
  left: 0;
}

.lb-nav a {
  outline: none;
  background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==");
}

.lb-prev,
.lb-next {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
  width: 34%;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background: url(../images/lightbox/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next {
  width: 64%;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  background: url(../images/lightbox/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-dataContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-dataContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-data {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.lb-data .lb-details {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-caption {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-number {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999999;
}

.lb-data .lb-close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../images/lightbox/close.png) top right no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.lb-data .lb-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 50px on your lb-outerContainer class and also on your lb-dataContainer class

```
.lb-outerContainer {
   position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* top: 50px; */
    top: 50px;
}
.lb-outerContainer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```